# Need assistance with SQL 2017 Installation Errors

Tags: sql-server, windows, installation, system

[image][image]
I get the error in the attachment during SQL Server 2017 installation. I would like some assistance please.

Comment: Posting the results of that log file is going to be really useful here.

Comment: I added new picture

Comment: But the log file is `text`... Post is as such. I (and I image other users), are unlikely to make an attempt to read that image; especially as the image doesn't appear to contain the whole log while (or the bits with the errors) anyway

Comment: Underneath the section of the Log where your image stops should be a detailed results section that documents each component failure. We need to see that.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the Pinal Dave post. It looks like he describes similar issue https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2016/03/07/sql-server-setup-closed-exit-code-0x80004005/

> All I can see is that there is something wrong with .NET security. I
>   asked my .NET expert friend to know if there is any tool to reset the
>   permission? He told CASPOL.EXE can be used to reset the policies.
>
> Caspol.exe (Code Access Security Policy Tool)
>
> So, we went into following directory
>   “C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727” and ran this
>   command: –  caspol.exe -machine -reset
>
> C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727>caspol.exe -machine
>   -reset
>
> If it would have been a 32-bit machine, we would have run the same
>   command under “C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727” folder.
>
> After doing above, the setup was able to start and finish as well.

Comment: I removed sql. reinstalled. gave the error in the picture during installation

Comment: You have to at least attach the log file

Answer (score 0):

Have you simply tried fully uninstalling and reinstalling? Including the .net frameworks? Usually, if you completely remove everything that is related in some way to SQL and reinstall, it should complete successfully.